# Locking checkbox position in Telerik Grid header context menu

Tags: telerik-grid

Locking the position of checkboxes in the header context menu

we have a grid where in user can select the columns, when user selects the additional columns, existing grid columns are getting shuffled, i want the newly selected columns to be added at the end of the grid.

can somebody help me here?